# Aframe Image with Depth one side only

Tags: aframe

I want to show an image with a frame. Using `<a-image>` gives me a plane with the image. 
`<a-box src="path/to/img.jpg>` however gives me the image but it's giving me the image 6 times. Is it possible to get the box with am image at the front and any color at all other sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this with Aframe (I don't think so), but you can do it with Threejs, by making an array of materials that contain a material for each box face, and applying that to the box mesh.

```
const loadManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(loadManager);

const materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-1.jpg')}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-2.jpg')}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-3.jpg')}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-4.jpg')}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-5.jpg')}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('resources/images/flower-6.jpg')}),
];

loadManager.onLoad = () => {
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate
};
```

you can place this code inside of a custom component that is attached the cube geometry.
[Here is the tutorial](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-textures.html) that the above code was taken from, on threejsfundamentals.

Comment: another way to do this would be to make the mesh and materials in a 3d app (ie blender) and export at gltf

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. For future readers, you can include your mesh in aframe with entity.setObject3D('mesh', cube)

Comment: care to share a simple glitch showing how to implement this in aframe? For future learners?

Comment: nice one! I added orbit-controls to more easily see the effect. https://glitch.com/~cube-multitexture